# Finding related items in Entity Framework across 2 hops

Tags: entity-framework-5

Here's the relevant part of my data model:

[image: data model]

I have a generic data entry screen which knows what entity it's on and builds a grid to edit the data for that table. Everything was going just fine until I got to Promises. I went to code it to load a drop down with services, then realized I didn't have enough information to load the list.

[image: generic data entry screen]

Here's the code for `Promise`:

```cs
namespace biz
{
  public class Promise: EFObject<Promise>
  {
    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    public decimal Hours { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Service")]
    public int Service_Id { get; set; }

    public Service Service { get; set; }

    public Constraint[] Constraints;
    //public Dollars Allocation { get; set; }
  }

}
```

As the human being who designed the system, I know that I must only load the services belonging to the member who owns the package who owns the promise. But as a generic data entry screen, how do I know that? I can't hard-code anything.

Is there a way I can annotate promises to indicate the list of services from which the service can be chosen among? Some kind of constraint (Service_Id must be from (select Id from Services where Member_Id = ?

Anything in Promises is fair game to the generic data entry screen, and as long as it's logical and consistent, I can apply the same rule to any entry screen anywhere in the entity catalog.

Comment: So, you're on a `Promise` maintenance screen as a `Member`? I guess you're looking for a way to build a query dynamically, for instance by using a predicate builder.

Comment: @GertArnold, hello sir, I added the screen shot for more background. I'm hoping there's a declarative way or a way to add another foreign key so that EF will know to only grab the services for the current member (when considering options to choose among) in the context of a promise of a package of that member. I see that currently my data model doesn't enforce this. Perhaps that's the first thing to fix. Thanks!

Comment: In the end, EF executes SQL. What can't be done in SQL (skipping a join) can't be done in EF. You need something like `where Promise.Package.Member_Id = memberId`.

Comment: @GertArnold, I think I need to start off by adding `Member_Id` to `Promises` and making the foreign key to `Services` (as well as the one from `Packages`) a compound foreign key; IOW, make the data model truly match my intent. Then my generic routine can generate the filter by taking all columns in `Services` that participate in the foreign key *except* the `Services` primary key column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the foreign keys as per [How to relate two unrelated foreign keys back to the same entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264507/how-to-relate-two-unrelated-foreign-keys-back-to-the-same-entity).

[image: fixed data model]

After that, I just needed to give the grid the brains to look at the compound foreign key and get the choices constrained by `Member_Id`.