# How to relate two unrelated foreign keys back to the same entity

Tags: entity-framework-5

Using EF code first, I created compound primary key on `Packages` and `Services` consisting of `Id` and `Member_Id`.

Then I made foreign keys from both of those tables into `Promises`.

[image: data model (wrong)]

As you can see it didn't relate the two foreign keys back to the same `Member` thus allowing the `package` member to be different than the `service` member. This is not what I intended.

I intend to have `Promises` just have a single `Member_Id` column and reuse it in both foreign keys. In problem terms, I intend for `promises` to only have `services` of the `member` that owns that `promise`'s `package`.

I can easily do this in the database. See this fixed diagram:

[image: data model (fixed)]

This features compound foreign keys from `Promises` back to `Packages` and `Services`.

How can I attribute my classes in EF to achieve this result?

Is my only option to Database First migration and check and see what it does to mimic what I did manually in the database diagram editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to:

1. Fix my database the way I wanted it
2. Create a new Class Libray Project
3. Add Entity Framework Model. Choose Code First from Existing Database
4. Look at the differences between my classes and the generated classes from Database First, and see which ones I need to apply to my model. In this case, I found that the only way to create the foreign keys I wanted was with code not attributes and this is done in the `OnModelCreating` routine in the model (`DbContext`) class:

```cs
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
          .HasMany(e => e.Packages)
          .WithRequired(e => e.Member)
          .HasForeignKey(e => e.Member_Id);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
          .HasMany(e => e.Products)
          .WithRequired(e => e.Member)
          .HasForeignKey(e => e.Member_Id);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
          .HasMany(e => e.Services)
          .WithRequired(e => e.Member)
          .HasForeignKey(e => e.Member_Id);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Package>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Promises)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Package)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Package_Id, e.Member_Id })
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Promises)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Service)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Service_Id, e.Member_Id })
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```